# Why is Blender Guru UV unwrapping?

Tags: uv

I am doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipYiwUmBfs8) tutorial of Blender Guru. And about 15 minutes he is UV unwrapping the mesh. Why is he doing that ? Although I am a beginner I think I understand the general purpose of UV unwrapping. Buy not what Blender Guru is trying to establish here.

Comment: UV unwrapping allows you to gain more control over how a texture is applied to the surface of the mesh. Without a UV map you can only map a texture through various automatic methods that rarely fit well on a complex mesh.

If view the part before and after the UV map is applied in the tutorial (around 15:50), you'll see how using the UV map affected and improved the look of the object.

Comment: He needs uv coodinates for the grunge texture introduced at min 18 and also use that to have better control on the procedural texture.

Answer (score 1):

The cube on the right is flattened/unfolded so a texture can be applied. On the left is what it looks like after it is unfolded. Where it is cut to unfold these are called seams. In the video he places the seams to unfold the object.

[image]

By creating a 2D view of the object you can add a texture in an external editor (for example) exactly where you want the texture to be. The 2D version is mapped to the 3D object ... UV Map

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's so he can place the texture on the model. Without unwrapping it first, you can't put a texture on. It's just how it works, you can't project a 2-d picture on a 3-d object unless it is also 2-d.